# Default T Pose altered in edit mode

Tags: armature, edit-mode

This is a really noob question which must have been answered somewhere but I can't seem to word my question adequately to find any posts that specifically answers my question...

Anyway, somehow I completely messed up by changing the positioning/angles of my T pose (A pose in this case) in edit mode and hit save+quit before realising I did. I'd know how to reset armatures back in pose mode but is there a right way of doing it in edit mode?

(I basically want the model in the image to be facing front/centred/angles adjusted etc but I'm not sure how to fix it properly)

[image]

---

.blend file is here if needed:

[image]

Comment: could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: I may be not comprehending your question exactly, but it seems that you only want to turn him around to face front & center.  If that's the case, select the whole armature  in Object mode, and rotate that in the Z axis.  If your character has been parented to the bone assembly, it should rotate also.

Comment: You can go in pose mode then select all and Alt+R to remove the rotations. Now, you have bones constraints here: disable them. After that you may have your rest pose. Last thing: Alt+R again on the armature in object model to be aligned with axis